# How a sleeping thread can send interrupt to itself?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading Java Threads. I am looking into `sleep()` method. The books states that

> When a thread encounters a `sleep` call, it must go to sleep for
>   specified amount of time, unless it is interrupted before its wake-up
>   time.

I am reading about interrupts, but how can a thread send interrupt to itself? I think so
another thread can send interrupt? Am i understanding correct? Additionally, do both of
the threads, one which will send the interrupt should be having same target Runnable? If
for suppose a thread is interrupted, does it go back to `Runnable` state? I am really sorry,
if i am sounding stupid, it's just pretty new for me. Thanks

Comment: When you want to learn Multithreading, it would be better to use ExecutorServices, they are much easier to used and more robust. Personally I think, using plain Threads is a little outdated and makes multithreading more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @Casey Even within the Executor framework, it is important to understand the interruption process.

Comment: @Casey, i am very new to threads, so first just brushing up the basics.

Comment: @assylias Using Thread.sleep while being executed by an ExecutorService is a grave mistake, in my opinion. You block the complete Thread und prevent other jobs from being executed. This can practically gripple the whole ExecutorSevice. If you want to execute some code after a time delay, you need to schedule an other task. The big advantage of ExecutorServices is that you don't need to care about the whole low level things like sleep/interrupt or wait/notify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Thread can't interrupt itself while sleeping, because it is... sleeping.

A picture is worth a thousand words so here is a simple example where a thread starts sleeping and the main thread interrupts it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runnable sleeper = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("sleeper is going to sleep");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("sleeper is awake");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("sleeper got interrupted");
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(sleeper);
    t.start(); //run sleeper in its own thread
    Thread.sleep(500); //sleeping in main a little to make sure t is started
    t.interrupt();
}
```

which prints:

```
sleeper is going to sleep
sleeper got interrupted
```

Comment: i am a little confused by your example. Here you are making sleeper to sleep() in the runnable. Then you are again making current thread to sleep() in main method. In this case, even main can sleep as it can be current thread also. Then you are invoking interrupt() on sleeper instance itself. Isn't it a little contradicting, that a thread can't interrupt itself. I am sure, i am perceiving example in wrong way, can you elaborate on it?

Comment: the sleeper is sleeping for 10 seconds, but because it's run in another thread and this thead isn't necessary created right away, the main will wait for 500ms (time enough to create the other thread) before interrupting the sleeper

Comment: Ah i get to see the picture now. Correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: @benz The Runnable is just a container for a task that can be run in the future by a thread. Declaring the Runnable does not run it because you need a thread to run it (in my case `t`). When you call `t.start`, two things happen: a new thread is created which will be able to run in parallel with the main thread AND the `run` method of `sleeper` is executed in that parallel thread. Then the main thread continues executing normally. So when `t.interrupt` is called, `t` has run for approximately 500 milliseconds and is still sleeping...

Comment: does that mean a thread can interrupt itself? One cannot tell another thread to interrupt right?

Comment: No prasad, one thread can interrupt the other thread for sure.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Yes a thread can interrupt itself by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`.

Answer (score 0):

As for the main question - Sleeping thread cannot interrupt itself because it sleeps, BUT any other thread can try to iterrupt the sleeping one. [Here you have doc explaining threads and thread lifecycle.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html)

Comment: Thanks @Antoniosss, i am a little confused, the thread which will send the interrupt, should it be having same Runnable as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only another thread can send an interrupt to a sleeping thread. It is not possible for a thread to send interrupt to itself(Simply contrast it to real life, if a person is sleeping then to wake him, we require some other person). And yes, after interrupting a thread goes back to `Runnable` state.

Comment: Second sentence bothers me, it IS allowed for thread to interrupt itself. Cut from Oracle docs bout interrupting threads "Unless the current thread is interrupting itself, which is always permitted..."

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know its another thread which causes the interrupt. So when a thread calls sleep for certain time, Java Runtime makes a note of this, and when time has passed, it causes the interrupt which wakes up the sleeping thread.

Comment: The second thread should not concern you while writing code. As this is the JRE thread which is running of code itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Thread#interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> Thread can interrupt itself.It is always possible.

Example is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, InterruptedException {   
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  try{
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);
  }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        System.out.println("Current thread is interrupted");
  }
}
```

invoking *interrupt* never throws exception.It set the *interrupt status flag*.
When  this thread is blocked in an invocation of the *wait()*, *wait(long)*, or *wait(long, int)* methods of the Object class, or of the *join()*, *join(long)*, *join(long, int)*, *sleep(long)*, or *sleep(long, int)*, methods of this class, then its *interrupt status will be cleared* and it will receive an InterruptedException.
or

Comment: Could you interrupt yourself when you are sleeping ? :D

Comment: A thread can interrupt itself, but not while sleeping. In your example, the thread never sleeps because when sleep is called, it realises that it has been interrupted and throws an exception immediately. Also sleep is a static method so you can just use Thread.sleep.

Comment: @assylias I agree with you